# Basic Auth in metro app using C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metroapp using C# and I'm stuck with calling web-service from my app which needs username and password to access it(which i have)  So, Can anyone explains me how to do Basic Auth to make a web-service call. Any links or articles with examples is appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried combining the whats-it with the thingamajig. (seriously though... not enough inforamation all all to provide any sort of sensible answer).

Comment: Dude - the Basic Auth is a foundation of the web. You really ought to be able to do some very 'basic' research yourself.

Comment: Consider reading something about the basic stuff ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.95).aspx) might be a good starting point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about Basic Http Authentication, if you're using HttpClient to make your web service calls then you can enable set a Basic authentication header with the following code.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password)));

request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);
```

The simplest (and cleanest) way, however:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uriString);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are referring to OAuth, and the implementation in Metro is actually not that hard as there is a Web Authentication ‪WinRT‬ API.- but as the devs that commented on your question suggested, you should have a good read if the topic is new to you. [Maybe start here, look at the documentation.](http://oauth.net/)

Pluralsight has many great videos on WinRT , and the Web authentication topic.
Look under Windows 8 --> Windows 8 Metro Connected Apps -->   Accessing HTTP Services --> WebAuthBroker [direct link here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents/win8connectedapps)

[As for an example app, you can find one here.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

[And here is an article fromj MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh465283)

Good luck!